# visual studio express 2012 properties of property sheet trouble

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm having a problem with lack of options in the property sheet properties of a project in c++.
the propery sheet has only general and no other properties like vc++ directions and so. How can I get to those options to include libs dlls and so on?

Comment: have you a cpp file in your project, can you open your vcproj as text with a text editor and update your question with that text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globally setting VC++ directories:

1. Open a project
2. Go to View->Property Manager
3. You should have something like "Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user" under "Debug|Win32", etc.
4. Double-click and add the default stuff (directories, libraries, etc.)
5. Hit Save in the Property Manager tab.

Now the changes you made should be inherited for all new projects.

To update [a single project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee855621%28v=vs.120%29.aspx):

> To specify or modify directory settings
>
> In Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the project you want
>   to change and then choose Properties.
>
> In the left pane of the Property Pages dialog box, expand
>   Configuration Properties and then select VC++ Directories.
>
> To modify one of the directory lists, select it, choose the down-arrow
>   button on the right, and then choose Edit.
>
> In the box in the dialog box that appears, you can add or remove
>   values, and you can rearrange the order in which the values appear.
>   You can also change whether the project inherits any settings by
>   selecting or clearing Inherit from parent or project defaults.

Comment: Thenx man, but I wanted to know if there is a way to do this to a property sheet and then just add it to every project instead of adding in the project settings every time.. (I think that that was your solution, my English is not one of my best features..

Comment: @user1729796 I've posted an answer in regards to your requirements.

Comment: thenk you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

First, create a new self-contained property sheet:

1. Open any project.
2. View > Property Manager
3. Expand the configuration with which you wish to add a sheet.
4. Click the "Add New Property Sheet" icon.
5. The sheet will default to every entry as "Inherit from parent or property defaults"
6. Edit any fields that need to be changed. Warning: The sheets listed are just links, if they are included in multiple configurations, ALL of them will be changed. I suggest you create multiple sheets for each configuration.
7. With the sheet selected, click the up/down arrow(s) in the property manager to move it up/down the inheritance tree. Higher sheets are imported after lower sheets and inherit properties from all sheets below it (when the field is selected to do so).
8. Click the "Save property sheet" icon.
9. The new property sheet can now be used for multiple projects.

Now, with a self-contained sheet available:

1. Open any project
2. View > Property Manager
3. Expand the configuration with which you wish to add a sheet.
4. Click the "Add Existing Property Sheet".
5. Navigate to and Select a previously created property sheet.
6. Move the sheet up/down the inheritance tree as needed.

Comment: Can you update this for VS Express 2013? Also, are you sure this applies to the Express versions?